Lookup field search layout
Hi I have created one new custom object. On case object I have created a new lookup field to this new custom object.
In case object I have already some other lookup fields with another objects, I am using these new field and old fields on vf page when I click on search mirror icon it is opening new window for all lookup fields but when compared to all old fields window with this new field the layout was totally different.
How can I get same layout to this new field, I found that this is due to new custom object by creating another look field with existing objects then working same. Only for the lookup from the New custom object working differently.
Can any one help me in this?
Old fields layout

New field layout


You can modify the list of fields displayed per each object search window in the target's object Search Layout/Lookup Dialogs. In your case, it will be the Product object.
In classic: Setup -> Objects -> Product -> Search Layouts -> Lookup Dialogs

In Lightning: Setup -> Object Manager -> Product -> Search Layouts -> Default layout

